# Access nested firestore collections or documents from Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a web app with Vue.js (this is the first time I use it). In my project I need to access to a cloud firestore database to read or to add some data. The database I created is characterized by nested collections and documents (see the screenshots below). My problem is access nested data in db.
For example given `export const db = app.firestore()` the reference to my cloud firestore database, I'm able to set a field in the document called "Medico" with the expression:

```
export default {
 data(){

  return{

   figures: []


  } 

 },   

 created(){


   db.collection("Utenti").doc("Medico").collection("Domande").doc("Domanda1").set({



       Testo: "prova"


   })
  }
 }
```

but when I try to access to a nested document to add a field with this :

```
db.collection("Utenti").doc("Medico").collection("Domande").document("Domanda1").set({


Testo: "prova")}
```

it is created a new collection "Domande" with a document "Domanda1", instead of using the existing one (see the screenshots below).
I have the same problem with reading a field. I want to know how exactly I have to access to a nested document or collection.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the console say when the set() fails?

Comment: I had a problem with the server, now it works but not properly. Infact it is created a new collection "Domande" , and within it a document "Domanda1" with the field "Testo" , instead of using the existent "Domande".

Comment: That sounds like you've just got the reference mixed up now. Please post *exactly* the code that's running now and a before/after image of the db.

Comment: I edited, moreover I tried to run another time (afterafter it has been added the new "Domande") the same code (this once I modified the value of "Testo") and this time it find "Domanda1" in "Domande" and modified the field's value, instead of adding another "Domande".

Comment: As danh indicated your code does not correspond to your print screens: if you used a new value (Testo) please update the print screens accordingly. For us to be able to help you we need to have the exact information: we are not in front of your screen :-)

Comment: Sorry I have mistakenly uploaded the wrong screenshot

Comment: Thanks! Actually your print screens correspond exactly to your code (`db.collection("Utenti").doc("Medico").collection("Domande").document("Domanda1").set({Testo: "prova")}`). What is your exact problem? It is not 100% clear. You  say "I want to know how exactly I have to access to a nested document or collection." -> can you explain with the exact documents and collection names what you want to obtain.

Comment: I thought the problem was related to my incorrect access to collections or documents. I realized that if I manually upload the firestore cloud database from my firestore account page, I am unable to read the existing values ​​of the document fields, or in case of addition I have the situation shown by the last screenshot that I  published. While if I populate the database from my application (using the add () and set () functions) then (when the database is populated) I am able to read or add the data correctly with the istructions indicated above.I want to know tha nature of this problem.

Comment: Normally there shouldn’t be any difference when reading data created through the console or through an SDK if the field types and values are similar. You say "I am unable to read the existing values ​​of the document fields", but **how do you read**? You don’t show any corresponding code for the reads.

Comment: I'm also not sure what the issue is exactly. Please provide some more information on how you are reading, what are you getting, and what is the expected outcome you want.